# Gradle basedir property

Tags: gradle

Is there an ANT equivalent basedir property in gradle?

```
${basedir}
```

I am trying to get the name of the directory where the build script is located.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Depending on your exact needs, you could use `buildFile.parent` or `projectDir`. (The build file path defaults to `"$projectDir/build.gradle"` and can be reconfigured in `settings.gradle`.) See the [Gradle Build Language Reference](http://gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/index.html) for which properties and methods are available on `Project` and other classes.

Comment: Thank you, I used projectDir.getName() to get the last directory name in the path.

Comment: For my needs, I was looking for `rootDir` which is the root directory in a multi-module project (`projectDir` is relative to the module). Another good reference for project variables is the [Gradle API for the Project interface](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Project.html).

Comment: yes this one fit my needs to. the other suggestions people were coming up with would not work when i ran from `gradle -p specifyBuildGradleFilePath`

Comment: Is there a list somewhere of all the default properties related to project structure? Something that includes `rootDir`, `buildDir`,  etc. Basically, everything that's usable in a string such as `"$buildDir/resources"`